# How to append html element one time when specific screen resolution range occurs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My html:

```
<div id="log">

</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var win = $(window);

    resizeHandler();

    win.resize(resizeHandler);

    function resizeHandler() {
        if (win.width() <= 700) {            
                $("#log").append("<div>" + "success" + "</div>");
        }       
    }
});
```

I want that when a specific screen resolution range occurs, the `<div>success</div>` element would be displayed one time in the "log" div element. For example: from 1 px to 700 px screen resolution the success must be displayed in the "log" div element one time, and when the screen resolution is out of the 1 px to 700 px range the `<div>success</div>` must be removed from the "log" div element. How should the code look like?

Comment: Can you not use media queries?

Comment: I dont know how i could with media queries append a html element. I need then something like this: @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) { $("#log").append("<div>" + "success" + "</div>"); }

Comment: You're right, you can't append. But you can hide/show the element which should ultimately have the desired effect. I guess I need to know more about your end-goal. What are your actually trying to do?

Comment: Your suggestion worked for me with the hide() and show(), thank you!

Comment: Ok your edit helps, but what do you mean by displayed "one time" do you want it to pop-up and fade? Or remain in place until the condition is no longer met?

Comment: Oh, I'm glad it helped, but that's not what I was suggesting. You really shouldn't use javascript for this problem.

Comment: I wanted it to remain in place until the condition is no longer met.

Comment: Then this is definitely something you need to do with media queries. I'll give you an answer that uses that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on information provided in the comments, you want a simple media query. No JS required. If that's what you really needed to do then [@nevermind's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32235919/1795429) was perfect.

Just change your code like this.

HTML:

```
<div id="log">
  <div id="success">Success</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#success {
  display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #success {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i am using at this time media querie with display and it works great!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
  var win = $(window);

  resizeHandler();

  win.resize(resizeHandler);

  function resizeHandler() {
    if (win.width() >= 700) {
      if ($('#log').children().length == 0)
        $("#log").append("<div class='suc'>" + "success" + "</div>");

    } else {
      $('.suc').remove();

    }
  }

});
```

If you really want to append just one element. But, i would use media queries too, and hide/show desired element...

Comment: Yes, it works now fine for me, i have fixed it with media queries, hide() and show(). thank you.

Comment: No, i meant your description where you writted "But, i would use media queries too, and hide/show desired element..." I have gotted the idea when you sayd it. But the jQuery works to, thanks!

Comment: @AlanasMacijauskas, yes, of course, there are many ways to do the same thing. CSS media queries are maybe more elegant way, in this case. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a boolean variable and set it to true when appending
+ create an else statement in your resizeHandler to cope with the other screensizes.

But in a real world example i would have solved this issue by using CSS mediaqueries.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I dont know how i could with media queries append a html element. I need then something like this: @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {  $("#log").append("<div>" + "success" + "</div>"); }

Comment: With media queries you would simply just add the <div>Success</div> to your html and give it a class lets say <div class="message-success">Success</div>  and hide/show it by using display:none/block in the media query.